# Is there any way to get all of the media queries used in a website?

Tags: css, layout, breakpoints

I have a premium WP Theme, and all i have to do is to implement some style changes.

The theme is responsive, but i don't know what are the layout breakpoints.

So i'm asking you if there are methods to discover the layout breakpoints without searching them into the theme stylesheets, thanks!

Comment: So you want to find something out without looking at the thing you need to change? Obviously you could re-size the browser, measure how wide the screen is to see where it hit the breakpoint, but that's pointless, when you can just look for `@media` in the `CSS`

Comment: Breakpoint tester will tell/show you all the breakpoints on a page http://breakpointtester.com/ Would that help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily see all the break points used on a page with [breakpointtester.com](http://breakpointtester.com/)